# How to populate an array from Access Database VB

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-access-2010

I'm looking to populate an array or set of variables from a selected SQL string.

I know the SQL string will give me 3 values from 3 different rows but I can't figure out how to assign each one seperately to a variable (I keep setting all 3 variables as each item)

I know the code isn't right but maybe it will give a better idea of what I'm trying to acheive:

```
        Dim network_default(3) As String
    network_default(0) = "Array item 1"
    network_default(1) = "Array item 2"
    network_default(2) = "Array item 3"

    Using dbConnection As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.SMSA_databaseConnectionString)
        Try
            dbConnection.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot create a connection to the database object")
            Application.Exit()
        End Try

        Dim sqlcommand As String
        sqlcommand = "SELECT Services.[Service], Services.[IP], Services.[Description] FROM Services WHERE (((Services.[Default])=True));"

        Dim getSomeData As New OleDbCommand(sqlcommand, dbConnection)
        With getSomeData
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@variableName", "variableValue")
        End With

        Using dataReader As OleDbDataReader = getSomeData.ExecuteReader
            Do While dataReader.Read
                For i As Integer = 0 To 3
                    network_default(i) = dataReader("IP")
                Next
            Loop

        End Using

        dbConnection.Close()
    End Using
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to set array index for each value and then set the value from the database.

Comment: Look more closely at your code. `Do While dataReader.Read` iterates through each row in the DataReader. As you `Read` each row the inner `For` loop is assigning all three values in the `network_default` array to the same value: the "IP" value for that particular row.